# Software updates

Tags: updates

I'd like to know if I can differ/delay the Software Updates on my computer because it is annoying for updates every ~ 2 to 3 hours. Let's say, I want to check the updates every Saturday (weekly or every 2 weeks).

Using kernel version: 3.13.0-37-generic
Linux Kubuntu 14.04 LTS

Any suggestion will be welcomed.
Thanks,
Abdon

Answer (score 0):

Search for and run software and updates and then click on the Updates tab.  You should be able to take it from here.